# UnauthorizedAccessException: Acceso denegado a ruta de acceso 'C:\'

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Estoy intentado descargar un archivo usando C# y .NET 4.7.2 a la misma carpeta en la que está el programa, pero el .NET Framework me tira este error:

*UnauthorizedAccessException: Acceso denegado a ruta de acceso 'C:'.*

Aquí está el código:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace Instalador_de_Bobi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
                    }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (WebClient fileDownloader = new WebClient())
            {
                fileDownloader.DownloadFile("https://www.google.com/index.html", @"\");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aténtamente,
Bobi

Comment: Para grabar en disco c:\ directamente requiere permisos de administrador.  Siendo el disco c:\ el del sistema de windows

Comment: Tienes dos opciones dar permisos a la carpeta o ejecutar el programa como administrador (el .exe)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por la seguridad de Windows. [Aquï](https://support-microsoft-com.translate.goog/en-us/windows/allow-an-app-to-access-controlled-folders-b5b6627a-b008-2ca2-7931-7e51e912b034?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=wapp) hay un enlace (traducido del inglés) donde MS explica como permitir para que haya acceso a carpetas. También puedes probar abriendo Visual Studio como administrador.